# Email forwarder not able to connect my SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, email, shared-hosting

I am trying to execute a small php script when I receive an email. I created a test@myhost.com address email and set up the forwarder to the script (just a connection to the database to save the subject and the from of the mail).

But I get this error :

> Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'server.myhost.com' is not
>   allowed to connect to this MySQL server Action: failed
>   Final-Recipient: rfc822;|/home/pipescript.php Status: 5.0.0

My host server is Bluehost.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: is scrip on same host as db

Comment: Yes it is, but the email is from gmail

Comment: looks like the host messed up to me

Comment: email the host, by default this should not happen if the php script and db server are hosted together

Answer (score 0):

This may caused by wrong user config of MySQL.

Go to your `mysql.users` table and check is the permission correctly set. Makesure the `host` column is set to `%`

If it helped you, please give me a vote. THANKS

Comment: I don't think it is the problem, the permission is set correctly

Comment: @AlphaNico So probably you want to check your MySQL installation & your firewall setting.